# Как сделать функцию поворота экрана в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpixmap, rotate, qtransform

Как сделать, что бы при запуске кода, начиналась функция поворота экрана?

Мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                              
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                  
        
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("iamge.png").scaled(400, 400)      # ваше фото
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""
            background: pink; 
            color: black; 
            border-radius: 34px;
        """)
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.setFixedSize(300, 150)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.eff = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.eff.setOpacity(0.0)        
        self.lbl.setGraphicsEffect(self.eff)
        
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.eff, b'opacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)       
        
    def show_image(self):
        if not self.btn.isChecked():       
            self.animation.setStartValue(1)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        else:    
            self.animation.setStartValue(0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(1)
            
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.btn.click)   # !!! 3000 + 4000 = 7000 

        self.animation.start() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(420, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QTransform &**QTransform**::**rotate**(qreal angle, Qt::Axis axis = Qt::ZAxis)
>
> Поворачивает систему координат против часовой стрелки на заданный угол
> вокруг указанной оси и возвращает ссылку на матрицу.
>
> Обратите внимание, что если вы примените QTransform к точке,
> определенной в координатах виджета, направление вращения будет по часовой стрелке,
> потому что ось Y направлена ​​вниз. 
> Угол указывается в градусах.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                              
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                  
        
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.lbl.setMinimumSize(500, 500)                              # +++
        self.lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)                   # +++
        
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("lena-2.png")  #.scaled(400, 400)     # ваше фото
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""
            background: pink; 
            color: black; 
            border-radius: 34px;
        """)
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.setFixedSize(300, 150)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.eff = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.eff.setOpacity(0.0)        
        self.lbl.setGraphicsEffect(self.eff)
        
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.eff, b'opacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)   

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, self.btn.click)                    # +++  

        self.rotation = 0                            
        self.num = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.rotate_pixmap)
        self.timer.start()

    def rotate_pixmap(self):
        self.num += 1
        if self.num == 25:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.num = 0
            return
    
        pixmap = self.pix.copy()
        self.rotation += 15
        transform = QtGui.QTransform().rotate(self.rotation)
        pixmap = pixmap.transformed(transform, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
    def show_image(self):
        if not self.btn.isChecked():       
            self.animation.setStartValue(1)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        else:    
            self.animation.setStartValue(0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(1)
            
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.btn.click)   

        self.animation.start() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(520, 600)                                               # +++
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я имел в виду не поворот картинки, а поворот самого экрана

Comment: @TFader пожалуйста, объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать. Попробуйте как-то изобразить что вы хотите получить.

Comment: В некоторых приложениях есть такая функция: при заходе срабатывает поворот экрана (поворачивается экран, во всех играх такое бывает)